# How do I create a temp table in Oracle SQL just like in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql, oracle

I saw a lot of examples online, but I'm still unsure on how to create a temporary table. The following example is how I create a temporary table in SQL Server:

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#processid') is not null truncate table #processid
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#processid') is not null drop table #processid

select distinct
    lot_id,
    ssr.run_oid,
    process_id
into #processid
from sigma.sigma_run ssr
inner join sigma.sigma_lot ssl on ssl.run_oid = ssr.run_oid
```

How can I create a temporary table just like this in Oracle SQL?

Comment: That's not a good idea in SQL Server to begin with - tables with arbitrary types and sizes, without any keys or indexes. Use staging tables instead

Comment: In both databases there may be better options, eg a view, perhaps even a materialized view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle, we usually do **NOT** create temporary tables.

Basically, it depends on what you want to do.

If you must, then you could e.g.

```
create global temporary table temp_table as
select distinct
    lot_id,
    ssr.run_oid,
    process_id
from sigma.sigma_run ssr
inner join sigma.sigma_lot ssl on ssl.run_oid = ssr.run_oid;
```

But, once again, you should explain what's *behind* the scene so that we could suggest what to do next.

Note that data in a temporary table is visible only to you; other users won't see anything. If you want to share data collected with that query, then create a "normal" table (i.e. remove `global temporary` from that statement).

Also, you could create a **view** (which is just a stored query) and then fetch data from it.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't use them either, somewhat lazy developers do. A table generated with arbitrary fields and sizes and no keys or indexes is *always* a bad idea.

Comment: @Littlefoot Thank you for the reply! I need to create a temporary table cause my colleague wants me to connect it to Tableau with another code that I've done in SQL server. That was what he suggested it to me.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thank you - fixed that. Sheesh, I added some more info - have  a look, please.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - SQL Server temp tables ***can*** be indexed and constrained.

Comment: @MatBailie the question uses `SELECT INTO` so the table will start without indexes and constraints. Even with `INSERT INTO` though the table is created in `tempdb` which is a very busy database.

Comment: @Littlefoot I didn't mean that the answer is wrong. Using temporary tables as a crutch is wrong. In fact, the very example [Oracle docs use](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/tables003.htm#i1006400) (airline reservations) is *extremely bad and cringeworthy* - I work for an online travel agency and the thought of having millions of temporary tables per day.......

Comment: Absolutely, @Panagiotis; the fact that temporary tables exist doesn't mean that they should be (ab)used. My previous comment was related to my own sentence about MS SQL Server; I don't use it so my "knowledge" (ha-ha) about it is mostly gathered by reading various forums' discussions; that's where I came to know about close connection between terms "MS SQL Server" and "temporary tables". That's why I decided to remove that line. Thanks again!

Comment: @Littlefoot I tried your method but I think its saying inappropriate INTO. What is it cause by?

Comment: Ah, sorry, Sheesh; remove INTO (see fixed code). It is inappropriate in this context (I just copy/pasted code you posted, without checking it properly). INTO clause is used in PL/SQL, as - in Oracle - you have to select result of the SELECT statement *into* something (a local variable, collection, whatever).